# Django textarea form

Tags: python, django

i need to set rows and cols for a textarea in my HTML page from Django but it doesnt work.

I already put rows and cols in mine form

> Views.py

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):

    title =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name':'title'}))

    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'name':'body', 'rows':3, 'cols':5}))

def new(request):
     return render(request,"encyclopedia/handlepage.html", {
       "title": "CREATE NEW PAGE",
        "edit": False,
        "editpage": EditForm()
     })
```

> handlepage.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
   {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<a href="https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/">Markdown guides</a>
{% if edit %}
    //Useless right now
{% else %}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'save' %}">
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE ENTRY"><br>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ editpage }} 
</form>


{% endif %}
  
{% endblock %}
```

Then my page should have a small text area but it have the same size independent by its row and cols like this
[image: handlepage.html]

Comment: does your browser  source reveal anything on that textarea tag of interest?

Comment: @AMG sorry for late reply. This is from Inspection textarea {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 80%;
}

Comment: I suspect your css is overtaking your attributes. In the `<textarea >` do you have a rows and cols set? Look to the source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and I think we are working on the same project because the screenshots look the same: was this **Project 1** for
**CS50’s Web Programming with Python and JavaScript**?

Anyway, I tried with

```
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":"5"}))
```

and it looked like it didn't work, but it was only because of a **CSS property already applied** that overrides the rows and columns attributes (as @AMG also suggested).

You can see this if you open your browser Inspector:

[image: screenshot of inspector]

You just need to **remove those two CSS properties for width and height** to see the rows and columns attibutes apply.

I know that you have probably already solved this issue, but I'm posting this because I guess that fellow CS50 students may still need this answer in the future.

Comment: Yes, it was the CS50 project. Anyway, thanks for replying. I hope it could be useful for someone

Answer (score 2):

Does adding it in init work? I forget the reason I had to do it this way but it's what I've been using (I may be out of date though).

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):

    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['body'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 3
```

or alternatively in meta:

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):

    # your fields defined here followed by Meta

    class Meta:
        fields = ['title', 'body' ]
        widgets = {
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
        }
```

Comment: neither solution worked. The size remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Write those numbers in the quotes. And see if it works.

```
body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'name':'body', 'rows':'3', 'cols':'5'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is changing the CSS style of the text-area.

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):

    title =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name':'title'}))

    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'name':'body', 
                                                        'style': 'height: 3em;'))
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer.
in Project1\wiki\encyclopedia\static\encyclopedia.there is a CSS file called
style.CSS.
in this file determines the Style of textarea.

```
"
textarea {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 80%;
}
"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDZCX.png)
delete this and all come back.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently working on this project and got into this same question. What I did was:

1. From your static/encyclopedia/ folder there is a CSS file called styles.css, find the textarea and comment it.

> styles.css

```
"
/*textarea {
height: 60vh;
width: 90%;
resize: none;
margin-top: 10px;
}*/
"
```

2. Then, in your views.py, where you created the "forms" class, on the textarea variable, add the wanted attributes.

> views.py

```
class NewPageForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(label="New Title",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'name':'title'}))
content = forms.CharField(label="Content:",widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'name':'content','style':'width: 90%; height: 60vh; resize: none; margin-top: 10px;'}))
```

With this you will have full control over the CSS of the textarea. Hope this answer helps for any future CS50 fellow having this question.